# From 2-wires to Dual LED (3-wires)

Tags: led, diodes, relay

I have a 2-wire cable going to a junction box. From that box, I connect to a dual LED lamp that has two positive terminals and one negative. Applying voltage to the first positive terminal turns on the white light, and applying voltage to the second positive terminal turns on the red light. To address this issue, I want to reverse the polarity of my power cable so that either the white or red light can be activated. I've created a circuit below using a relay and 5 diodes.

My question is, can this be done with fewer components or in a simpler way? The junction box is located outside, so I prefer to use as few components as possible.
Additionally, I cannot use a ground or common ground in the junction box.

[Falstad circuit (editable)](http://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEBmAHAJmgdgGzoRmACzICcpkORICyNNkNApgLRhgBQASuGOuLhBUBOKGKKN01RjOgIOAd3BTUKdIz5FVRYZEXhIUkOlSqwkU8ct6A5igT801ZDlVOxesFjcP7-KYzIvqL8MKFQsEjm8HARhsaykGBIMIhQHAAmvKjO6spaapIgGUwAZgCGAK4ANgAumdnUJmYqVqr8JRU19V6qqLHIkNSkOIFDQuARjrDkOqik6qTeRAhYWKxgoqlRMbGp-onJcZAp%20iOSluZGzelK54UGlsh5elkIfCjjCAufTcVlVTq%20m%20jnGOAQokG0gaOmcwQhfmM-y6QKy4Mh8Mh4w6AO6%20k07UurWeMjOoxQLhA91htyECKhIH6Y2hSnRiKZiL0d3JNIJIBpr35whpNKC-mRgPqbw%20NPeoL%20nUl%20hI8poHwZXP5z0Rot8mrlQuoIt0wJlwmpJqUHLFjIGlL0ACMtQZREQJGqtsrtTafXqvaqfeNHVS1sYwKRlHg1Vh0gAPcC0Gg6NSqBBECNNagABQA9tVygAnACWtQAngAdADOlYUJYAxgALJgFjjxq7UNP8PhfFb84zUAAilXK1SrUgAagOAMJVgAyTAyrd4RBjyHd7CwdDXdGoHy4AFEB0v2L30DgY%20xUHR0FhGLv%20AB1AASAEkACr7pfkRzroZIbd9h8AAO1SVJWVYABQFguACUX6kBAN5mCcSAmBA94gCBYGQQoDYlkwcHxuQO4IDsxD8gQgH8AAtkWAB2S7qHQEIhOCNA4BmAggPusa1M2dEjseFhIBCu7EDGEIxruMY8XxBYCdUX5NJSySIWQVEgFwC4APQPnhfEcJsXYWG4eSXrkRSKt0LDVAukwyHEnBGY8hJmGAORtEiVl1DZdkQP5jn4j8NwBJ5mrhv4lw-C4qjhdFrj9oECW2IlFIhEYyD2ukdihSSxgZS86SVrwXaCJsGiCA5FTVJWTAcMV5UJGY5L4FskzVbVQX%20AiEVhfiLU9eS7jhUNHm5R5I0VaIjXqLFQkXiQ4DrsmGEAPJ0dpq2lKUS4OLu6kcsQ-CZiAABiBY5tRY4sLW0HgZWtQ5lWQ4jnOh79VN4A-F4npKL1P1fd1npoGIp0QIwLDXNQbAgOOea1OUNh1UAA)

[image: Falstad circuit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with just diodes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHFDSS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but I have no internal access to the light. It's a sealed PAR36 light with only 3 wires, coming out. (2 plusses, 1 minus)

Comment: @Thom If you draw a box around those LEDs you will see there are 2 plusses and 1 minus just like your LED.